# Help me find my mistake in this question on finding the population after 2 years from a model

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

**Question**

Suppose a population is modelled by the logistic equation such that the population after t years is given by

$P(t)=\frac{1,000}{1+5e^{−kt}}$ for some constant k.

If the initial population is doubled after one year, then what is the population after two years (to the nearest whole number)?

---

**My solution**

First since we need to find k, we need to use the given information that the population is doubled:

$$\frac{1000}{1+5e^0}=2 \cdot \frac{1000}{1+e^{-k}}$$

$$\frac{500}{3}=\frac{2000}{1+e^{-k}}$$

$$1+e^{-k}=12$$

$$e^{-k}= 11$$

$$k=-\ln 11$$

Therefore

$$P(t)=\frac{1,000}{1+5e^{t\ln 11}}$$

So since the question is asking the population after 2 years:

$$P(2)=\frac{1,000}{1+5e^{2\ln 11}}$$

$$=\frac{1,000}{1+5e^{\ln 11^2}}=\frac{1000}{1+5(11^2)}=1.65$$

This answer is **incorrect**, and I have to admit that it seems obviously wrong too, because 1.65 for a population is not a realistic answer.

However, I can't find any mistake in my working either and I have tried it over and over again. **Really appreciate if anyone can shed some light into what I am doing wrong over here.**

Comment: You have the 2 on the wrong side when you get started.

Comment: @alex.jordan OMG :O how silly :O

Comment: @alex.jordan thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equality is not correct.  We have

$$P(0)=\frac{1000}{6}$$

and we are given that $P(1)= 2P(0)=\frac{2000}{6}$.  Then,

$$P(1)=\frac{1000}{1+5e^{-k}}=\frac{2000}{6}\implies1+5e^{-k}=3\implies \bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{k=\log (5/2)}$$

Thus, we can write

$$P(t)=\frac{1000}{1+5\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^t}$$

and for $t=2$ we have

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{P(2)=\frac59 1000}$$

Comment: You're welcome!!  My pleasure.

Answer (score 1):

You have the 2 on the wrong side when you get started. The way you have it, the population begins at some level, then is half as much 1 unit of time later.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If the population double in one year, then you have to multiply the initial population by 2. Only then you can set the two terms equal.
$$2\cdot \frac{1,000}{1+5e^{−k0}}=\frac{1,000}{1+5e^{−k\cdot 1}}$$

Now you can solve for k.

Comment: You are welcome.